# Java: Syntax error on token "}"?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax, system, printf

Attempting to write some code to convert feet to meters and meters to feet and achieve the table shown below. This is my first java program and I have no idea why I'm getting syntax errors involving "}".

```
Feet Meters| Meters Feet
1.0 0.305  | 20.0 65.574
2.0 0.61   | 25.0 81.967
…
9.0 2.745  | 60.0 196.721
10.0 3.05  | 65.0 213.115
```

Here's what I have...

```
public class Hmwk {
public static void main(String[] args){

public static double footToMeter(double foot){
    return 0.305 * foot;
}
public static double meterToFoot(double meter){
    return 3.279 * meter;
}
for (double i = 1.0; i <11; i++){
    System.out.printf(i+footToMeter(i)+"|"+(i*5+15)+meterToFoot(i*5+15));}
}}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Methods cannot be nested.

Comment: You have no closing brace for your `main` method and `for` is outside any method.

Comment: That's some awfully ugly code. Curly brackets are not meant to stay on the same line with the rest of the code.

Comment: Know that your problem would be a lot easier for you and us to see and identify if you took the time and small effort to format your code well. I suggest that you start doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small tip, if you don't like indenting code, then coding might not be for you.

This may sound harsh, but I sincerely believe that before one writes his/her first program, one needs to know what code structure is all about. Unfortunately, schools and courses tend to hide or ignore this fact completely. I know, I've seen this back at secondary school - telling your teacher to properly format code isn't nice believe me.

```
public class Hmwk {

    public static double footToMeter(double foot){
        return 0.305 * foot;
    }

    public static double meterToFoot(double meter){
        return 3.279 * meter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        for (double i = 1.0; i <11; i++){
            System.out.printf(i + footToMeter(i) + "|" + (i*5+15) + meterToFoot(i*5+15));
        }

    }
}
```

1. In Java, you cannot have methods inside methods.
2. Indenting code means you can find your problems easily.
3. Brackets are meant to stay on separate lines, except the opening brackets (depends on taste)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of braces in incorrect positions. Most notably, your `footToMeter` and `meterToFoot` are declared inside of your `main` method, which is incorrect. Here is your code with correct brace placement:

```
public class Hmwk 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (double i = 1.0; i <11; i++)
        {
             System.out.printf(i+footToMeter(i)+"|"+(i*5+15)+meterToFoot(i*5+15));
        }
    }

    public static double footToMeter(double foot)
    {
         return 0.305 * foot;
    }

    public static double meterToFoot(double meter)
    {
         return 3.279 * meter;
    }
}
```

As a general rule, methods cannot be nested in Java. This means that no method can be declared inside of another.

Answer (score 0):

No closing brace in the void main. Put '}' before 'public static double footToMeter' and delete closing bracket after closing bracket from `for`

Comment: He has a closing `}`, it's just that he was declaring methods within `main`.

Comment: The closing brace is hidden at the end of the for-loop, but it's there.